# React Router no funciona en producción

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

Tengo un proyecto de **ReactJS** que al compilarlo a desarrollo navega por cada una de las rutas sin problema, pero al compilarlo a producción e intentar navegarlo en `apache (xampp)` saca error `404 not found`.

Vale la pena aclarar que estoy usando **Webpack**

La ruta en la que lo intento navegar es algo como `http://localhost/proyectos/proyecto/`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header }>
                <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } />
            </Layout>
        }/>

        <Route path="/panelcem" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelCem info={ this.item('/panelcem') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route path="/panelplanner" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelPlanner info={ this.item('/panelplanner') } />
            </Layout>
        } />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

He intentado incontables "soluciones" encontradas en internet pero ninguna me soluciona el problema, simplemente al navegar en producción se muestra una pagina en blanco, sin errores en consola.

Como prueba agregué una última ruta:

```
<Route render={() => {
    return(<h1>Prueba/h1>)
}} />
```

Y el resultado es que sin importar a que ruta acceda siempre le entra a la última que agregué. No reconoce ninguna de las otras rutas.

Ya agregué el **.htaccess** y el resultado es una simple página en blanco.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: quizá esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357947/react-app-on-server-while-refreshing-the-page-shows-404-page

Answer (score 2):

Buen día, no sé si esto vaya a ayudar pero siempre es recomendable poner la ruta "/" al final a menos que uses " **exat path='/'** ".

Recordemos que el enrutador devuelve el componente devuelto por el primer componente Route con el que hace match y el **la ruta "/" es muy genérica provocando que haga match con cualquier otra rutra**.

Por lo tanto siempre, bajo cualquier ruta renderizará esa primera ruta que definiste.
Es decir el siguiente:

```
<Route path="/" element={
   <Layout header={ this.state.header }>
      <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } />
   </Layout>
}/>
```

Las rutas siguiente rutas también harán match con el componente Route anterior.

- "/"
- "/panelcem"
- "/panelplanner"

Mi sugerencia es que agregues **la propiedad "exact" antes del "path", eso le dice a React Router que sólo haga match en esa Route cuando la url sea exactamente "/"**. 
Algo así:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={
   <Layout header={ this.state.header }>
      <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } />
   </Layout>
}/>
```

La otra opción es llevar ese componente Route al final de los otros Route's. De esta forma eso significa que hará match con cualquier otra ruta que no haga match con las anteriores "/panelcem" o "/panelplanner". 
Algo así:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/panelcem" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelCem info={ this.item('/panelcem') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route path="/panelplanner" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelPlanner info={ this.item('/panelplanner') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route path="/" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header }>
                <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } />
            </Layout>
        }/>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Cualquier ruta que comience con "/panelcem" hará match con la primera. Cualquier ruta que comience con "/panelplanner" hará match con la segunda y cualquier otra ruta que no haga match con la anterior hará match con la última porque cualquier ruta comienza con "/". 
Sugerencia adicional, se suele poner como ruta genérica y al final de todas una sin ningun path como tu prueba para que si renderiza una página personalizada de 404 Not found.
Mi propuesta final sería algo como este:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header }>
                <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } />
            </Layout>
        }/>
        <Route path="/panelcem" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelCem info={ this.item('/panelcem') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route path="/panelplanner" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelPlanner info={ this.item('/panelplanner') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route element={
            <div>
              <h1>Página no encontrada 404<h1>
              <h2>La URL a la que ingresaste es incorrecta.</h2>
            </div>
        } />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Si no tienes una página 404 otra buena idea es poner un componente "Redirect" en vez de ello, por ejemplo. (No olvides importarlo). Algo así:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header }>
                <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } />
            </Layout>
        }/>
        <Route path="/panelcem" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelCem info={ this.item('/panelcem') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route path="/panelplanner" element={
            <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar } useLayoutStyles={ true }>
                <PanelPlanner info={ this.item('/panelplanner') } />
            </Layout>
        } />

        <Route element={
            <Redirect to='/' />
        } />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Espero que te ayude, de todas formas puedes enviarme un mensaje para tratar de ofrecerte una mejor respuesta por más detalles.

Comment: Gracias por responder, usando exact tampoco navega, sin importar que ruta coloque siempre entra a la ruta establecida para el 404, es como si no reconociera ninguna de las otras rutas :c

Comment: Otra consideración que se pueda hacer es que me pareció un poco extraño que uses la propiedad "element" de Route. Eso me hizo pensar que quizá ese "Route" es un componente personalizado. ¿verdad? Porque he estado revisando la API de React Router DOM y la propiedad del componente "Route" para señalar el componente que quiere renderizar es "component".  He estado probando en este sandbox el uso de la propiedad "component" de los componentes "Route". Si el componente "Route" que usas no es uno que hayas definido tú quizá debas cambiar la propiedad correspondiente.

Comment: Yo estuve jugando en este sandbox para probar la API de React Router DOM. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic 
Ahí podrías probar el uso del componente "Route".

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy usando la versión 6 de React router Dom, de hecho si te fijas bien en vez de switch se usa routes, yo aumente la versión a la 6 pensando que me daría solución ya que en la versión anterior me pasaba lo mismo, evidentemente aumentar la versión no funcionó tampoco

Comment: Vale, ya estoy revisando la documentación y el pase de la v5 a la v6 y voy entendiendo más tu código. Ese problema lo podrías aislar en un proyecto esqueleto  sin data sensible para que no haya problemas con que lo puedas subir a un repositorio y así poder examinarlo más a profundidad. Porque quizá se necesie más detalles.

Comment: Vale ojalá puedas ver algo que yo no haya visto por qué ya he buscado en absolutamente todos los lados y nada me ha funcionado, estoy llegando a pensar que es una mala configuración en el .htaccess pero no sé, de igual forma te agradezco mucho tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

tu puedes crearte un archivo Routers

```
const Routers =() => {
    return(
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Comments} exact />
                    <Route path="/theme" component={Theme} exact />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

en tu archivo App.js solo renderizas el componente Routers

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <Routers></Routers>
    )
  }
}
```

bien ahora en tu `index.js` lo agrupas a tu app

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

y ahora te creas un archivo history que solo tendra la importacion, para usarlo en varios componentes:

```
import { createBrowserHistory as history} from 'history';

export default history();
```

ahora en tu archivo que quieras usar la navegacion lo importas y lo usas

```
import history from './history';
  <div><Button onClick={() => history.push('/theme')}>see</Button></div>
```

estas son mis dependencias:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
```

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 6.0.0 de react router, funcionaría igual?

Comment: @BenderPaisa edite mi respuesta, puse mis dependencias, espero te sirva

Comment: Justo estoy implementando tu respuesta, bajé mi versión de react router dom, te cuento que sucede

Comment: No funcionó :c, pasa lo mismo, en desarrollo es perfecto pero en producción no muestra nada, no renderiza el componente de home nisiquiera, y si intento navegar a otra ruta saca 404 not found

Comment: @BenderPaisa talves es problema cors?

Comment: No lo se :c realmente solo llevo dos semanas en React y he visto muchas soluciones en internet como agregar un .htaccess y otras cosas pero ninguna me ha servido, cuando agrego el .htaccess el error de 404 not found desaparece pero la página continúa mostrándose en blanco

Answer (score 0):

¿Tu app fue creada con Create React App?

Si es así, échale un ojo a la [documentación](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#web-server).

Traduzco un poco de lo que creo que tiene que ver con tu problema:

> El servidor web debe ser configurado a través del paquete de construcción estático.
>
> El archivo de configuración `static.json` debería ser entregado a la raíz del repositorio.
>   No será reconocido, si este archivo está en un subdirectorio.
>
> Este es el static.json por defecto, si no existe en el repositorio, es:
>
> ```
> {
>   "root": "build/",
>   "routes": {
>     "/**": "index.html"
>   }
> }
> ```

Si no estoy mal "/**" indica que recibe cualquier tipo de enrutamiento como el que indicas (`/proyectos/proyecto/`). Deberías probar crear el archivo con esta configuración por defecto, o crear una para una sola ruta y hacer la prueba. Aunque esa ruta por defecto es la que permite que una SPA se enrute fácilmente con React Router, si está por defecto así debería funcionar.

Comment: No, uso una configuración de webpack creada desde cero, en ese caso también serviría esta solución?

Comment: No lo sé, pero si la creaste tú mismo deberías revisar esa configuración de las rutas, en caso de que las tengas declaradas.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/